# Не показывается реклама admob

Tags: android, admob

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь добавить рекламу в свое приложение, все по инструкции https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start.

Сначала добавил строчку в build.gradle (module: app)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Изменил манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

+

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

+

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Добавил

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

Изменил .xml файл

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

+

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Добавил в код активити:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

+

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

При рендеринге в android studio видно место под баннер, но при запуске приложения баннера нет

```
05-05 15:14:49.746    1386-1386/su.worldbest.bbdd W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
05-05 15:14:49.770    1386-1386/su.worldbest.bbdd W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
05-05 15:14:49.790    1386-1389/su.worldbest.bbdd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 3% free 8742K/8976K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 14ms
05-05 15:14:49.802    1386-1386/su.worldbest.bbdd I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
05-05 15:14:49.814    1386-1386/su.worldbest.bbdd I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
05-05 15:14:49.818    1386-1386/su.worldbest.bbdd I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("D5C4A6CB58FB68100CD3CBDF39CB8F22") to get test ads on this device.
05-05 15:14:49.870    1386-1398/su.worldbest.bbdd D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1062427778.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
05-05 15:14:49.894    1386-1398/su.worldbest.bbdd D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads-1062427778.jar' (success) ---
05-05 15:14:49.894    1386-1398/su.worldbest.bbdd D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/su.worldbest.bbdd/cache/ads-1062427778.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 22ms
05-05 15:14:50.330    1386-1405/su.worldbest.bbdd I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
```

Баннера не видно ни на эмуляторе, ни на реальном устройстве. Что делать?

Comment: Для использования данной библиотеки необходимо, чтобы на телефоне было установлено обновление для Google Play Services. Проверьте - у вас в логах `Google Play services is missing.`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое время не мог понять почему не виден баннер, хотя делал все по инструкции!

Оказалось, что баннер часто не виден только потому, что, банально, **не влазит** (по размеру) в то пространство, которое Вы ему отвели. И, в основном, по ширине!

Нужно смотреть размеры и ограничения (особенно **padding**'и) всех охватывающих его LinearLayout'ов, GridLayout'ов, ScrollView и т.п. 
Т.е. просмотреть размеры (еще раз: особенно **padding**'и) всех родительских Layout'ов по всей иерархии общего макета страницы (*.xml)

К сожалению, никаких предупреждений (сообщений) на этот счет не делает Android Studio (3.0.1) до сих пор. А надо бы!!! Пора уже! )

Answer (score 2):

У меня то же самое было. Помогло удаление внутренней разметки файла `activity_main.xml`
Удалить все строчки:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

и.... Ура! баннер появляется! =)